# Getting wrong answers for palindrome

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I'm having trouble with this palindrome code. When I try to run this in leetcode I'm getting an error. Help me find the error.

```
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
let xToString = x.toString();
let reversed = x.toString().split(' ').reverse().join('');
if(x < 0 ) return false;
if (xToString === reversed) {
    return true;
}else return false;
```

if X is a palindrome number it returns true but if i give let say 20 its also returing true.

Comment: you split it by whitespace `.split(' ')` it should be `.split('')`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you split it by whitespace, try `.split('')`

```js
var isPalindrome = (x) => x.toString() === x.toString().split("").reverse().join("")


console.log(isPalindrome(20))
```